# Update value of attribute with count condition requirement

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a data query result from query

```
select count(type_of_vegetation)as count,type_of_vegetation 
from tb_patrol 
group by type_of_vegetation
```

as shown below:

```
count | type of vegetation    
1     | Semak Belukar, Pepohonan   
2     | Pakis, Sawit, Senduduk     
1     | Pakis, Sawit, Ilalang, Akasia   
49    | Sawit    
15    | Pakis, Karet   
17    | Semak Belukar
```

I'd like to update the value of "type of vegetation" which has value of count that is less than 15 into "Others" but with condition group by type of vegetation, as in the example below:

```
count | type of vegetation    
1     | Others   
2     | Others    
1     | Others
49    | Sawit
15    | Pakis, Karet
17    | Semak Belukar
```

I use postgres SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery and `IN` operator:

```
UPDATE tb_patrol 
SET type_of_vegetation = 'Other'
WHERE type_of_vegetation  IN (
   select type_of_vegetation 
   from tb_patrol 
   group by type_of_vegetation
   having count(type_of_vegetation) < 15
);
```